# How to import routes flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am a beginner with Flask and I have created a project with an MVC structure

- **CODE :**

```
.
├── app
│. │── main.py
│  ├── controllers
│  │  ├── dbscan.py
│  │  ├── home.py
│  │  └── kmeans.py
│  ├── models
│  │  ├── dbscan.py
│  │  └── kmeans.py
│  ├── static
│  │  └── XXXX
│  └── views
│     └── XXXX

└── main.py
```

File `main.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(
    __name__,
    template_folder='app/views',
    static_folder='app/static'
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

File `home.py`

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

- **ISSUE :**

I already understood the problem but I don't know how to fix it...

There is no link between the `controllers` files and the `main.py`

So, how I can link all routes present in `controllers` folder and `main.py` ?

- **UPDATE :**

`home.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

home_hdl = Blueprint('home_hdl', __name__, template_folder='views')

@home_hdl.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask

from app.controllers.home import home_hdl

app = Flask(
    __name__,
    template_folder='app/views',
    static_folder='app/static'
)
app.register_blueprint(home_hdl)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Folders

```
.
├── app
│  ├── controllers
│  │  ├── __init__.py
│  │  ├── dbscan.py
│  │  ├── home.py
│  │  └── kmeans.py
│  ├── main.py
│  ├── models
│  │  └── XXXX
│  ├── static
│  │  └── XXXX
│  └── views
│     └── XXXX
└── XXXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1. Define a handler in each of the files you have under the controllers folder (the ones that will handle routing).

   E.g. for the `dbscan.py`, you could have

```
    from flask import Blueprint
    dbscan_handlers = Blueprint('dbscan_handlers', __name__, template_folder='views')

   # Your routes (in the dbscan.py file) will then be something like this
   @dbscan_handlers.route('/xyz/'):
    .....

   @dbscan_handlers.route('/def/'):
    ....
```

2. Then you register the handler in `main.py`

```
    from controllers.dbscan import dbscan_handlers
    app.register_blueprint(dbscan_handlers)
```

3. Note that to do `from controllers.abc import xyz`, you need to have an `__init.py__` file in controllers. The file can be empty.
4. When someone accesses your app, it will go to main.py and if the route is of the pattern `/xyz/`, it will be handled by dbscan.py file

Comment: Thank you for this information. But I still have this problem, if I use `from controllers.dbscan import dbscan_hdl` I have this error` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'controllers'` even with the `__init __. Py`
If I use `from app.controllers.home import home_hdl` I don't have this error but this one when I go to `localhost:5000/` -> `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'kmeans'. Did you mean 'kmeans_hdl.kmeans' instead?`
I don't understand what is wrong

Comment: I looked at your directory structure again and realized that ```app``` is a folder and the controller folders are under it and ```main``` is on same level as app. I thought ```app``` was your project folder. I don't actually see an advantage to having a parent folder for controllers. You can just drop it. Also I don't understand the relationship between home_hdl and kmeans. From your names, they are different files. You need to have a handler for each of the files

Comment: Indeed, you're right, I move the `main.py` into the app folder, it makes more sense because I have Docker files and others (I update initial post)
However, I still have the same error :/
`werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'kmeans'. Did you mean 'kmeans_hdl.kmeans' instead?`

Comment: It's okay, that was another problem, I fixed it,
In my view files I was using url_for () without thinking about Blueprint!
I pass the subject to resolved
Thanks again !